# Perform matrix multiplication between two arrays and get result only on masked places

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two dense matrices, **A** [200000,10], **B** [10,100000]. I need to multiply them to get matrix **C**. I can't do that directly, since the resulting matrix won't fit into the memory. Moreover, I need only a few elements from the resulting matrix, like 1-2% of the total number of elements. I have a third matrix **W** [200000,100000] which is sparse and has non-zero elements on exactly those places which are interesting to me in the matrix **C**. 
Is there a way to use **W** as a "mask" so that the resulting matrix **C** will be sparse and will contain only the needed elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a matrix multiplication is just a table of dot products, we can just perform the specific dot products we need, in a vectorized fashion.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

iX, iY = sp.nonzero(W)
values = np.sum(A[iX]*B[:, iY].T, axis=-1) #batched dot product
C = sp.sparse.coo_matrix(values, np.asarray([iX,iY]).T)
```

Comment: Good use of `sp.nonzero` there! Could be a faster alternative. Do you mind if I mention it in my post? :)

Comment: `sp.nonzero` and `sp.find` are nearly identical - returning the attributes of a `coo` format.  `find` just returns the `data` attribute as well.  If `W` is already `coo`, just use its `row` and `col` attributes directly.

Comment: `scipy.nonzero` is `np.nonzero`, which in turn defers to `W.nonzero`.  On further examination, `sparse.find` is slower because it takes a  round trip through `csr` format to sum duplicates.  `iX, iY = W.row, W.col` is even faster (if W is  already coo).

Answer (score 3):

First, get the indexes of the non zero places in W, and then you can just get the `(i,j)` element of the result matrix by multiplying the i-th row in A with the j-th column in B, and save the result as a tuple `(i,j,res)` instead of saving it as a matrix (this is the right way to save sparse matrices).

Comment: If you flesh out your answer a bit more, I believe this is the proper way to go with this problem.

Comment: This is certainly a possible solution. However, it would include iterating over 200m elements (1% of 200000x100000). I'd prefer a vectorized solution (if there is one)

Comment: If you have complete lines with only zero elements in W, you can zero the corresponding lines in A, and the same if you have complete columns with just zeros - you can zero the corresponding elements in B - and then use `scipy.sparse` to multiply the matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for a vectorized solution -

```
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

# Get row, col for the output array
r,c,_= sparse.find(W)

# Get the sum-reduction using valid rows and corresponding cols from A, B
out = np.einsum('ij,ji->i',A[r],B[:,c])

# Store as sparse matrix
out_sparse = coo_matrix((out, (r, c)), shape=W.shape)
```

Sample run -

1) Inputs :

```
In [168]: A
Out[168]: 
array([[4, 6, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 8, 1, 3, 7],
       [2, 8, 3, 2, 2],
       [3, 4, 1, 6, 3]])

In [169]: B
Out[169]: 
array([[5, 2, 4],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [7, 7, 2],
       [5, 7, 5],
       [8, 5, 0]])

In [176]: W
Out[176]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [177]: W.toarray()
Out[177]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

2) Using dense array to perform direct calculations and verify results later on :

```
In [171]: (A.dot(B))*W.toarray()
Out[171]: 
array([[52,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [73, 57,  0],
       [84,  0, 56]])
```

3) Use the proposed codes and get sparse matrix output :

```
In [172]: # Using proposed codes
     ...: r,c,_= sparse.find(W)
     ...: out = np.einsum('ij,ji->i',A[r],B[:,c])
     ...: out_sparse = coo_matrix((out, (r, c)), shape=W.shape)
     ...:
```

4) Finally verify results by converting to dense/array version and checking against direct version -

```
In [173]: out_sparse.toarray()
Out[173]: 
array([[52,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [73, 57,  0],
       [84,  0, 56]])
```