# How to speed up matrix multiplication in numpy if I only need the belt around the diagonal?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I need to compute a second power of a square matrix A (A*A^T), but I am only interested in the values around the diagonal of the result. In other words, I need to compute dot products of neighboring rows, where the neighborhood is defined by some window of fixed size and ideally, I want to avoid computation of the remaining dot products. How to do this in numpy without running the full matrix multiplication with some masking? The resulting array should look as follows:

```
a1*a1  a1*a2  0      0      0      0
a2*a1  a2*a2  a2*a3  0      0      0
0      a3*a2  a3*a3  a3*a4  0      0
0      0      a4*a3  a4*a4  a4*a5  0...
0      0      0      ...
...
```

The example matrix contains dot products for neighboring rows. Each row is multiplied only with its left and right neighbour. The zeros should ideally not be computed by the solution in order to save time. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830710/perform-matrix-multiplication-between-two-arrays-and-get-result-only-on-masked-p)
seems to be headed in similar direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into [sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) with `scipy` (where `numpy` is also from).

For your specific problem:

1. The diagonal elements are the column-wise sum of the elementwise product of your matrix and its transpose `v = np.sum(np.multiply(A, A.T), axis=0)`
2. the off diagonal elements are the same, just with the last row/column deleted and substituted by a zero column/row at the first index:

```
pos_offset = np.concatenate((np.zeros((n, 1)), A[:, :-1]), axis=1)
v_pos = np.sum(np.multiply(A, pos_offset.T), axis=0)
# similar for the negative offset diagonal
```

3. you can then construct the diagonal matrix with `np.diag(v)`:

```
A_res = np.diag(v) + np.diag(v_pos, k=1) + np.diag(v_neg, k=-1)
```

Comment: was about to answer it but clicked on submit by reflex. sorry.

Comment: A nice solution. Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit more on how to avoid the full matrix multiplication with scipy sparse?

Comment: Actually I might need to correct myself here - this is not a sparse matrix problem at first. Afterwards it is sparse but not until you completed the computation.

Comment: On more comment though: bear in mind that the solution I proposed is probably only much faster if your matrices are really big! Bumpy does quite smart vectorization, so a matrix multiplication up to the size of 1000s of rows/columns is still fast. I don’t have my computer with me to time that but you should see if it’s necessary.

Comment: I see, so this solution still requires the full multiplication right?

Comment: no, this solution does not require the full matrix multiplication, mut 3 elementwise multiplications. less than that if in my opinion not possible (you definitely need some products since those are the entries fo your result).

Comment: for an N x N matrix, matrix multiplicatin requires N x N x N multiplications while elementwise products require N x N multiplications. You see that unsell you have N or more elementwise multiplications to make, this is faster.

Comment: Oh ok my bad, I misinterpreted the np. Multiply to be matmul.